# PJSIP is Not Logging (Android)

Tags: android, pjsip

I am making my own app with PJSIP and PJ_LOG is not working (calling works).

Code is below, please HELP!!!
Thanks!

```
status = pjsua_create();
if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) error_exit("Error in pjsua_create()", status);
/* Init pjsua */
{
pjsua_config cfg;
pjsua_logging_config log_cfg;

pjsua_config_default(&cfg);
pjsua_logging_config_default(&log_cfg);
cfg.cb.on_incoming_call = &on_incoming_call;
cfg.cb.on_call_media_state = &on_call_media_state;
cfg.cb.on_call_state = &on_call_state;

__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,"INIT","PJ_LOG_MAX_LEVEL %d", PJ_LOG_MAX_LEVEL); //PRINT 5!!!

status = pjsua_init(&cfg, &log_cfg, 0);

if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) error_exit("Error in pjsua_init()", status);
}
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,"INIT","PJ_LOG_MAX_LEVEL %d", PJ_LOG_MAX_LEVEL);//PRINT 5!!!

PJ_LOG(1,(THIS_FILE, "Trying log %d", 1));//NOT PRINTING
PJ_LOG(2,(THIS_FILE, "Trying log %d", 2));
PJ_LOG(3,(THIS_FILE, "Trying log %d", 3));
PJ_LOG(4,(THIS_FILE, "Trying log %d", 4));
```

Comment: can you help me compiling pjsip

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is different logging tools using (android and pjsip). For android you have to use `__android_log_print` only. No other works. But to catch pjsip logging output you have to override pjsip log writer:

```
#include <android/log.h>

extern "C" {
    static void log_writer(int level, const char *data, int len)
    {
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "pjsua", data);
    }
}

/** Callback wrapper **/
static void on_cli_config(pjsua_app_config *cfg)
{
    pjsua_cb_orig = cfg->cfg.cb;
    cfg->log_cfg.cb = &log_writer;

    /* Override pjsua callback, e.g: to install renderer view */
    cfg->cfg.cb.on_call_media_state = &on_call_media_state;
}
```

You can found this example with pjsua sources: `pjsip-apps\src\pjsua\android\jni\pjsua_app_callback.cpp`

Comment: DenisKolodin - Thank you!